# How to show that a lognormal distribution approaches normality for a small coefficient of variation?

Tags: normal-distribution, asymptotics, lognormal-distribution

I note that the lognormal distribution approaches a normal for a small coefficient of variation, but I'm having a hard time showing this mathematically. Can someone help?

Comment: One way is to note that $(e^{\sigma X} - 1)/\sigma=O(\sigma)$ and apply that to a standard Normal variable $X.$

Comment: whuber, I'm going to need more help than that. Where, for example, did (^{}−1)/=() come from? And, how might one "apply" this to the standard normal variable? Apologies, but I'm just not that sophisticated.

Comment: It came from a standard definition of the exponential function as a MacLaurin series, $e^x = 1 + x + x^2/2 + \cdots.$ "Apply" means *let $X$ have a standard Normal distribution.*

Comment: I've been trying things like that, trying to find a series for $(1/\sigma)\exp(-1/\sigma^2)$. For small sigma, it doesn't seem to help.

Comment: That's irrelevant.  The relevant series is the one in my first comment, because that's based on the *definition* of a Lognormal variable.

Comment: I'm going to need a bit more hand holding. Can you show that the pdf of the lognormal approaches the pdf of the normal in the limit of small coefficient of variation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a special case of a general phenomenon; and analyzing the generalization enables us avoid almost all details of Lognormal distributions.

**Here's the sketch of the general idea.**  Suppose $Z$ is any random variable (in the application it will have a Normal distribution) and $g$ is a real-valued function differentiable in a neighborhood $\mathscr U$ of $0$ with nonzero derivative there, $g^\prime(0)\ne 0.$ (In the application $g$ will be an exponential function).  By definition, this means

$$g(z) = g(0) + g^\prime(0)z + zh(z)$$

where $\lim_{z\to 0} h(z) = 0.$

The general claim is that

> As $\sigma\to 0,$ the distribution of a suitably normalized version of $Y = g(\sigma Z)$ approaches the distribution of $Z.$

In the application, $\sigma$ is directly related to the coefficient of variation (CV) and $Y$ has a Lognormal distribution.  *All* Lognormal distributions arise in this way.

The "suitable normalization" must be

$$\frac{g(\sigma Z) - g(0)}{\sigma g^\prime(0)} = Z + \sigma\, (Z h(\sigma Z)).$$

*The remainder term on the right cannot wholly be controlled by shrinking $\sigma,$* because $Z$ can be arbitrarily large, leaving us unable to say anything about the magnitude of $h(\sigma Z),$ no matter what (nonzero) value we use for $\sigma.$  However, to high probability we can approximate $Z$ by a bounded variable $Z_K$ in which $Z$ is replaced by some bounded quantity whenever $|Z|\gt K.$ When $K$ is large enough, the distribution of $Z_K$ is essentially that of $Z.$  By then making $|\sigma|$ suitably small, $\sigma Z_K$ lies in the arbitrarily small interval $[-|\sigma|K, |\sigma|K] \subset \mathscr U.$  The differentiability of $g$ at $0$ implies that within this small interval, $g$ is well approximated by an *invertible linear* function: that is, it is just shifting $Z_K$ (by $g(0)$) and rescaling it (by $\sigma g^\prime(0)$).  Consequently, undoing this shifting and rescaling recovers $Z$ to an arbitrarily good approximation with arbitrarily high probability, *QED.*

---

All lognormal distributions arise as the distributions of variables $Y_{\mu,\sigma} = \exp(\sigma Z + \mu)$ when $Z$ has a standard Normal distribution with distribution function $\Phi.$  The value of $|\sigma|$ determines the coefficient of variation and grows small as the CV grows small.  What we want to find, then, is a limiting distribution for $Y_{\mu,\sigma}$ as $|\sigma| \to 0.$

Because the CV reflects the spread of $Y$ relative to its mean, **$Y_{\mu,\sigma}$ approaches a constant.**  At left, to illustrate, is a histogram of 100,000 realizations of $Y_{-1/2, 1/100}.$

[image]

**More insight can be had by suitably Normalizing $Y.$**  Let us consider what happens to $$\left(e^{-\mu}\,Y-1\right)/\sigma = \left(e^{\sigma Z} - 1\right)/\sigma$$

as $|\sigma|\to 0.$  (Its histogram is shown in the right panel of the illustration.)  To do that, let's estimate its distribution function,

$$\Pr\left(\left(e^{\sigma Z}-1\right)/\sigma \le t\right).$$

Using the Maclaurin series for the exponential, and taking $|\sigma|\le 1,$ it is immediate that

$$\bigg| \frac{e^{\sigma Z}-1}{\sigma} - Z\bigg| = |\sigma|\,\bigg| \frac{Z^2}{2!} + \frac{\sigma Z^3}{3!} + \cdots\bigg| \le |\sigma|\,e^{|Z|}$$

for all $Z.$  Let $\epsilon \gt 0$ be very small, ensuring there is $z_\epsilon \gt 0$ for which $\Phi(-z_\epsilon) \le \epsilon/4,$ meaning $$\Pr(|Z| \ge z_\epsilon) \le \epsilon/2.$$

Let

$$0 \lt \sigma \le \frac{\epsilon}{2}\,\exp(z_\epsilon),$$

thereby guaranteeing

$$Z - \frac{\epsilon}{2} \le \frac{e^{\sigma Z}-1}{\sigma} \le Z + \frac{\epsilon}{2}\tag{*}$$

provided $-z_\epsilon \le Z \le z_\epsilon.$

Since $z_\epsilon\to\infty$ as $\epsilon\to 0,$ this shows the distribution functions of $Z$ and $(e^{\sigma Z}-1)/\sigma$ are arbitrarily close provided $|\sigma|$ is sufficiently small. Consequently, the limiting distribution of the latter is the distribution function of $Z.$  That's your result:

> As $\sigma$ approaches $0,$ the distribution of the standardized variable $(e^{-\mu}Y_{\mu,\sigma} - 1)/\sigma)$ approaches the distribution of $Z.$

As a further illustration, here is a simulation of 100,000 Poisson$(3)$ values for $Z:$

[image]

A close look at the right panel shows the histogram begins to deviate from a Poisson probability distribution for values exceeding $6$ or so: the bars, which in the limit will be located only at integral values, appear to be sliding a bit to the left of those integers.  This is what $(*)$ means: for small finite values of $\sigma,$ both the heights *and the positions* of values on the graph of the distribution function might be displaced a little, as limited by $\epsilon/2.$  But as $|\sigma|$ decreases, the graph eventually settles down to the distribution function of $Z$ itself.

Comment: whuber, thank you for this. I remain concerned, however, about one thing, the
consistency of the spaces we're working in. 

In your proof, you seem to be working in ln(x)-space, where ln(x) are already
normally distributed. I would think that we'd want to consistently work in 
x-space, where x is log-normally distributed,

$p(x) = \frac{1}{x \sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(-\frac{\ln x - \mu}{2\sigma^2}\right)$

Comment: The CV of the log-normal in x-space is 

$\left(\exp \sigma^2 -1\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}$.

I suppose this implies that as the CV approaches zero then $\sigma \rightarrow 0$.

Assuming this, then, in x-space we'd want to show that $p(x)$ approaches the 
normal pdf in x-space as $\sigma \rightarrow 0$. I have been absolutely unable to
demonstrate this.

Comment: Your question is about the asymptotic behavior of $Y.$  That's what I analyze and highlight in the text and the figures.

Comment: My question is about the asymptotic behavior of p(x), not p(ln(x)). I'd like to see a proof that p(x) approaches normality as CV is small. You might be seeing the problem differently from me, but I think my question is clear.

Comment: Your question is clear, and that is what I answered.  Your "p(ln(x))" refers to the distribution of my $Z,$ while your "p(x)" refers to the distribution of my $Y,$ which is the subject of my analysis and is the variable discussed in my conclusions or figures.

Comment: I see. Let me study this. Appreciated.

Comment: After some parameter experimentation, I've found that $p(x) = \frac{1}{\sigma x \sqrt{2pi}}\exp\left(-\frac{(\ln x - \mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)$ is, for small $\sigma$, well approximated by $g(x) = \frac{1}{\sigma m \sqrt{2pi}}\exp\left(-\frac{(x - m)^2}{2m^2\sigma^2}\right)$, where $m=\exp(\mu)$. Note that $g(x)$ is normal, but with a standard deviation that scales with the mean $m$. This is, essentially, what I'd like to prove analytically, but, like I say, I've only landed on it by experimentation (and a small amount of intuition).

Comment: My proof is analytical.  If you only want to approximate $p,$ use its Taylor series centered at $m.$  But you will still run into the problem that any Normal approximation will fail for sufficiently large or small values of $x,$ so you still need to reason along the same lines (by arguing that those failures occur with such small probability that they don't affect the limit).  And, by using the density (instead of the distribution function) for your analysis, you complicate it unnecessarily because you have to deal with the combinations of limits and integrals.

Comment: whuber, I will look into these issues. I appreciate your help and advice.

Comment: @whuber: +1 for a great answer and congrats on reaching 300K rep.  I just had the honour of pushing you over that line with the upvote for this answer!

Comment: @Ben That is singularly kind of you.  I hadn't noticed.  But we are all, if only a little bit, numerologists at heart, aren't we?  And small multiples of high powers of integers are always memorable :-).